# Problem with uploading image in react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, create-react-app, react-props

I'm settin up a new store with sample pictures in a gallery. The source of the img path is in my product.json file, and it looks like this:

```
{
  image: "../../data/images/model/sample-picture.png"
}
```

This is just a dummy data to test the code, so don't worry about product names.

I get data due redux-state, and I'm passing it through components. I know that the format of data (output) is correct, cos I get in a console right result/format/path in the final component.

Normaly using non-imported path the result is ok, I can see the pricture in the gallery loading correctly. However when I try to use props as the source of my img src there is no image.

Here are some ss examples, that doesn't work: (I'm using create-react-app).

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgphY.png > doesn't work

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YcwM.png > doesn't work

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbhNm.png > doesn't work

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TaYB.png > this actualy works fine.

[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CW3k.png > doesn't work

[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5kU6.png > doesn't work

I know that I must use require(url) to properly load an image.
It works only with position 4 where I put direct path without variables, props etc.

[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVEw.png > here is the part

```
src={this.props.image} - doesn't work
src={require(this.props.image)} - doesn't work
src={require({this.props.image})} - doesn't work
src={require(`${UriImage}`)} - doesn't work
src={require("../../data/images/8/sample.png")} - WORKS
```

Here's some code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Col } from "reactstrap";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

import ProductModal from "./ProductModal.component";
// STYLES
import "../../styles/storeStyles/_singleProductCard.scss";

class ProductCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.image);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col className="single-product-col" lg={2}>
        <Card className="single-product-card">
          <Card.Img
            src={require("../../data/images/8/iphone8-gold-select-2018.png")}
            className="single-product-card-image"
            variant="top"
          />
          <Card.Body className="single-product-card-body">
            <Card.Title className="single-product-card-title">
              {this.props.name} {this.props.memory}
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text className="single-product-card-txt">
              {this.props.price} PLN
            </Card.Text>

            <Button
              className="single-product-card-button"
              onClick={this.toggle}
            >
              detail
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: Please avoid images of code and instead add the relevant code directly into your question's description.

Comment: @EmileBergeron just added the full component code. There is a problem with dynamicly inserting the src path from props. I need to combine it with `require()`, but I can't set it correctly. Any advice?

Comment: `require` is only available in NodeJS (by default) and your `this.props.image` variable is a client-side thing, so the app will fail to compile or just fail to work unless you find another way to load files dynamically, but that implies playing around with different babel/webpack configuration and plugins.

Comment: Also, the question's title mentions uploading images and your question is only about importing an image path dynamically. You should clarify one or the other.

Comment: Well, my bad with the title. I fixed the problem with `src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + this.props.image}`, but I read that you should not put images into your public folder. So I think the webpack config is the only way

Comment: _"you should not put images into your public folder."_ It really depends on your use-case. For static images that are hard-coded into your project, it's a good practice to ensure that they are processed in your bundling pipeline with webpack plugins for optimizations and cache busting name hashing, etc. But for dynamic image paths coming from data, it's really up to you what feels the best.